# Delphi 5.0 Interbase/FireBird connection problems

Tags: database, delphi, firebird, interbase, dbgrid

I'm having some problems in visualizing the data on a DBGrid.

I'm using Delphi 5.0 and I have a Interbase 6.0 DB with 50MB size

Some tables have about 32000 elements they are huge ones.

I'm using Interbase stuff such as:

- IBTable
- IBTransaction
- DataSource1
- Database
- DBNavigator

create the connection.

I do stabilish the connection but the data is not diplayed.

There are any problems related to wrong Component configuration. I think the problem is something related to the size of my DB and how Delphi handles the Data.

For example: If on the TIBDatabase I set the AllowStreamedConnected to true the data is diplayed.

- Is there any other specific info I have to set in order to make the DB data to become visualizable?
- Is there something in Delphi or Interbase/Firebird I can change to make the data visible?
- Maybe it is something on the Interbase/Firebird Connector???

Answer (score 2):

1. Put TIBDatabase, TIBTransaction, TIBTable, TDataSource and TDBGrid components on your form.
2. Set Database properties: database name, login, password etc.
3. Link Transaction property **Default database** to your Database.
4. Link IBTable properties **Database** and **Transaction** to your Database and Transaction
5. Connect DataSource to IBTable.
6. Set Grid datasource property to your datasource.

Then write OnCreate event for your form. Something like this:

```
...
Database.Connected := True;
Transaction.StartTransaction;
IBTable.Open;
...
```

That would be enough to see your data in the grid.

PS: IBTable is here only for compatability reasons. Use IBDataSet instead.